# Can I make a switch statement to ask if a bool equals to true?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing a Tic Tac Toe game and want to check if the following buttons were clicked. (Which if true, means you have won.) I think a switch statement is more efficient for that, but its red underlined and I don't understand why.

Here is my current code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tic_tac_toe2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        bool buttonisclicked = false;
        bool buttonisclicked1 = false;
        bool buttonisclicked2 = false;
        bool buttonisclicked3 = false;

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clickedButton1 = (Button)sender;
            clickedButton1.Text = "X";

            if (clickedButton1.Text == "X")
            {

                buttonisclicked1 = true;
            }
        }

        public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clickedButton2 = (Button)sender;
            clickedButton2.Text = "X";

            if (clickedButton2.Text == "X")
            {

                buttonisclicked2 = true;
            }
        }

        public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clickedButton3 = (Button)sender;
            clickedButton3.Text = "X";

            if (clickedButton3.Text == "X")
            {

                buttonisclicked3 = true;
            }
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
            clickedButton.Text = "X";

            if (clickedButton.Text == "X")
            {

                buttonisclicked = true;
            }
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
            clickedButton.Text = "X";

            if (clickedButton.Text == "X")
            {

                buttonisclicked = true;
            }
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
            clickedButton.Text = "X";

            if (clickedButton.Text == "X")
            {

                buttonisclicked = true;
            }
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
            clickedButton.Text = "X";

            if (clickedButton.Text == "X")
            {

                buttonisclicked = true;
            }
        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
            clickedButton.Text = "X";

            if (clickedButton.Text == "X")
            {

                buttonisclicked = true;
            }
        }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
            clickedButton.Text = "X";

            if (clickedButton.Text == "X")
            {

                buttonisclicked = true;
            }

            void Win()
            {
                switch (buttonisclicked)
                {
                    case bool buttonisclicked1 && buttonisclicked2 && buttonisclicked3 = true:

                        Console.WriteLine("Won");
                        break;
                }


            }
        }
```

Do I have to get rid of the break; or can't I use the && operator?

Comment: "I think a switch statement is more efficient for that" - more efficient than what? A simple `if` statement? No, it's not - and I would strongly advise against worrying too much about efficiency at this point anyway. While it's worth keeping an eye on "large scale" efficiency (e.g. whether you're using an O(n) or O(n^2) algorithm for something that might need to deal with a lot of data) what you're looking at here is *micro-optimization*. For the moment, I'd advise you to write the simplest code that works.

Comment: Well, you can figure out what that red wiggly line tells you by two means: Look into the error list panel in Visual Studio. There should be an error message corresponding with that red wiggly line. Or just hover with the mouse directly over the red wiggly line and a tooltip will pop up telling you the error message. You just have to read the message then. Don't worry, the error message should be in English... You might also want to lookup the documentation and/or a tutorial about switch/case in case you aren't sure about how to use switch/case properly even when looking at the error message...

Comment: By the way, of course you can use a switch statement to test whether a bool variable is true (or false). But it usually is not really useful to do so, as a switch/case based on a bool variable is nothing more than a convoluted and overcomplicated form of the simple `if (myBoolVar) ... else ...` or `if (!myBoolVar) ... else ...`

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I like what you are trying to do, but for something as simple as a boolean (which could only be true or false), an **if statement** is all you'd need:

```cs
if (buttonisclicked1 && buttonisclicked2 && buttonisclicked3) {
    Console.WriteLine("Won");
}
```

and if you want something to happen if it returns false, just add to the previous code:

```cs
else {
    Console.WriteLine("Lost"); // <-- Replace this with whatever you want
}
```

Good luck with your project! Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When doing a tick-tack-toe game it's better to separate your scoring logic from your events.

You should create this variable in your form:

```
    private Button[][] _buttons = null;
```

Then in the `Form_Load` do this:

```
        _buttons = new []
        {
            new [] { button1, button2, button3 },
            new [] { button4, button5, button6 },
            new [] { button7, button8, button9 },
        };
```

Now you can create a method that returns a list of strings that slices the grid horizontally, vertically, and by diagonals:

```
    private IEnumerable<string> GetSlices() =>
        Enumerable
            .Range(0, 3)
            .SelectMany(n => new[]
            {
                String.Join("", Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(m => _buttons[m][n].Text)),
                String.Join("", Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(m => _buttons[n][m].Text))
            })
            .Concat(new[]
            {
                String.Join("", Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(x => _buttons[x][x].Text)),
                String.Join("", Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(x => _buttons[x][2 - x].Text))
            });
```

Then, whenever you update the text on a button, you can work out who won like this:

```
        var slices = GetSlices();

        if (slices.Any(s => s == "XXX"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("X Won!");
        }

        if (slices.Any(s => s == "OOO"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("O Won!");
        }
```